# Renaming files in a wordpress folder via jquery / jscript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to run a script that will run every 5 minutes in a shared hostings wordpress folder that will rename the newest CSV file in that folder.

```
/wp-content/csv/sample.csv
```

I tried putting a js file in the folder within that folder and run it.

```
var fs = require('fs');

function runClear() 
{
    fs.readdir("", (err, files) => {
      files.forEach(file => {
        console.log(file);
      });
    })    
}

runClear();
setInterval(runClear, 300*1000);
```

However, it seems like I got client side and server side scripting confused. It seems like I need node.js.

What would be the best approach for this?

Regards,

Comment: If you are going to rename just, create a PHP file to rename the file and put that it cron.

Comment: Ahh- completely forgot about cron jobs. I have added the php file and see if it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right you are confused in client side and server side script.

Javascript is a client side script which deal with all the user interactions like what will happen user click something or submit a form, hover over some element, scroll the web page etc.

Where as server side script like php deals with data stored on server like mysql records or the physical files.

what you are trying to do is to change the server resource from client side script. and you can not do that directly.

Instead you can call an ajax function which send an HTTP request to some script placed on server. And in that server script write the code to read the existing files in a directory and rename them using file handling operations.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll try a cron job first as suggested above and see how I go.